# img height 100% of table row

Tags: html, css, html-table

If I have HTML like this:

```html
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <img src="a.png">
      </td>
      <td>
         <p>Sunday</p>
         <p>Sunday</p>
         <p>Sunday</p>
         <p>Sunday</p>
         <p>Sunday</p>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

The second column can have a variable number of paragraphs, so the height will be different. Whatever height the row is, I want the image to be that height. I tried this:

```css
img {
   height: 100%;
}
```

but it didn't seem to do anything. I would like to avoid changing the HTML if possible, can I do this with only CSS?

Comment: I know you don't want to change the HTML, but IMO, since it doesn't look to be tabular data, I'd recommend against using a `<table>`, it may make the styling easier

Comment: Why not make `a.png` the `background-image` of the `<td>`?

Comment: @StevenPenny Are there any classes or ids that you could target with your CSS?

Comment: @StevenPenny is the image always going to be the same?  Is it landscape or portrait in shape?

Comment: I feel like you could use object-fit: cover; then set the width to 100% instead of height and that would get you close.  But it might be helpful if your table is always the same width too.  Maybe one of the object-fit properties will work out.  Here's a sample I did on W3:  https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GI8K9OUM4FX7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the reason I wanted to increase the height of the image, was because the
second column can be much larger, which pushes the image way down with the
default table vertical centering. Instead of focusing on the image size, I
instead just moved the image to the top:

```css
td {
   vertical-align: top;
}
```

If someone has a solution to the original question I am still interested, but
this should do as a workaround.